# Ruby Jabber/Jingle library

Tags: ruby, xmpp, libjingle

Do you know any well documented library for handling Jabber's Jingle (audio/video) extension in Ruby ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think one exists, unless XMPP4R can handle it.